# ExternalContext equivalent for non jsf application

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets

trying to change one jsf application using jsp, servlet and java, in jsf application we were using

```
ExternalContext exctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
InputStream var= exctx.getResourceAsStream("/dir/file.xml");
```

tried to replace **extc** with **FileInputStream**, always getting filenot found exception.
In JSF application this is working well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Servlets, you should use the `ServletContext` to load an external resource.

```
InputStream var = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/dir/file.xml");
```